# Username "username" does not exist. translation

Tags: php, symfony, translation, fosuserbundle

Having some trouble with a translation with Symfony2. I am using the FOS User Bundle and the translation for error messages during login are working perfectly fine with this in the FOSUserBundle.fr.yml :

```
"User account is disabled.": "Ce compte est désactivé."
"The presented password is invalid.": "Mot de passe incorrect."
"The presented password cannot be empty.": "Vous devez saisir un mot de passe !"
'Username "%s" does not exist.': 'L'utilisateur "%s" n'existe pas.'
```

Except the last one, the translation does not work at all...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Username "%s" does not exist.': 'L'utilisateur "%s" n'existe pas.'
```

Single quotes are mixed up.. try something like

```
"Username \"%s\" does not exist.": "L'utilisateur \"%s\" n'existe pas."
```

or

```
'Username "%s" does not exist.': 'L\'utilisateur "%s" n\'existe pas.'
```